# HTML to Pdf using Rotativa and MVC with dynamic content - having blank space on header portion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I am using `Rotativa`(v 1.7.3) for converting HTML to pdf in my MVC application.

My objective is creating pdf--

- Having html header (dynamic)
- Having html footer.(static )
- Content is a partial view ( dynamic and model bineded )

**With the static header and footer everything is working fine but while I am using dynamic header I am getting a blank pdf page instead.**

**Action Methods:**

```
public ActionResult Print(long workOrderId)
   {
        WorkOrderVM objWorksOrderVM = new WorkOrderVM();
        // Data population code goes here
        string footer = Server.MapPath("~/Views/WorkOrder/WODetailPrintTemplateFooter.html");

        string customSwitches = string.Format("--header-html  \"{0}\" " +
                               "--header-spacing \"0\" " +
                               "--footer-html \"{1}\" " +
                               "--footer-spacing \"10\" " +
                               "--footer-font-size \"10\" " +
                               "--header-font-size \"10\" ", Url.Action("Header", "WorkOrder", new { area = "" }, "http"), footer);

        return new PartialViewAsPdf("WODetailPrintTemplate", objWorksOrderVM)
        {
            CustomSwitches = customSwitches
        };
   }

 [AllowAnonymous]
 public ActionResult Header()
   {
     WorkOrderVM objWorksOrderVM = new WorkOrderVM();
     // Data population code goes here
     return View(objWorksOrderVM);
   }
```

The `Header` action method is never hitted. The issue is may be in the `Url.Action` or what ?

**Update:**

The `Header` action method is now getting hitted as I have commented `SessionExpiaryAttribute` from the controller. The main purpose of that attribute is redirecting to Session expiry page once session is expired.

Now the problem is

- I am getting a blank space on every page at the position of header.
- Why Session is expired in `Header` action method.

I have uploaded a screen shot of the generated pdf here.

[image]

Header html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<body style="border: 0; margin: 0;">
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" height="157">
                model binding will come here.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try debugging, and see customSwitches value before return new PartialViewAsPdf, my friend.

Comment: This is my customSwitches  "--header-html  "http://localhost:5400/WorkOrder/Header" --header-spacing "10" --footer-html "E:\Projects\Somax Azure\SOMAX_V2\DEV\Presentation\Website\Client\Views\WorkOrder\WODetailPrintTemplateFooter.html" --footer-spacing "10" --footer-font-size "10" --header-font-size "10" "